# How to handle different rate-limits for an API?

Tags: elixir

I built a wrapper for an API that was *working* but now the company decided to implement different rate limits for their endpoints, since this is for a game they have servers and each server has different limits, for example, the EUW server has a limit while North America has another one but they provide the same information for their players. Now, I implemented a GenServer which takes care of these different rate limits but I can't figure out a way of handling rate limits for developers keys which are 20r/1s or 100r/2m. By default I implemented the first limit, 20 requests each second but that's not always true. I'm using ExRated to handle the requests.

**What I'm looking to get done**: A way of handling both, short term and long term limits on development keys.

On the function that does the requests I have something that I think I'd need to get rid of, it's just a placeholder for now.

```
  def get(region, rest, opt) do
    url = Map.get(@endpoint, region)

    if Mix.env() == :prod do # This part
      # Enforcing the time and amount of requests per method if
      # opts provided
      opt_time = Keyword.get(opt, :time)
      opt_amount = Keyword.get(opt, :amount)

      region
      |> ExRated.check_rate(opt_time, opt_amount)
      |> parse(url, rest)
    else
      region
      |> ExRated.check_rate(time(), amount())
      |> parse(url, rest)
    end
  end
```

The else statement above is the one that I would like to fix to support both development limits.

EDIT Based on first comment:

```
defmodule Godfist.LeagueRates do
  @moduledoc false

  # Handles checking the information passed and assigning the correct
  # limit to the request.

  use GenServer

  alias Godfist.HTTP

  # Rates for different servers.
  @rates [
    # "League" endpoints/servers
    euw: {300, 60_000},
    na: {270, 60_000},
    eune: {135, 60_000},
    br: {90, 60_000},
    kr: {90, 60_000},
    lan: {80, 60_000},
    las: {80, 60_000},
    tr: {60, 60_000},
    oce: {55, 60_000},
    jp: {35, 60_000},
    ru: {35, 60_000},
    # other endpoints
    match: {500, 10_000},
    matchlist: {1000, 10_000},
    champion_masteries_runes: {400, 60_000},
    static: {10, 3_600_000},
    other: {20_000, 10_000}
  ]

  # API
  def start_link,
    do: GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, %{}, name: :league_limit)

  def handle_rate(region, rest, endpoint \\ nil) do
    GenServer.call(:league_limit, {:handle_rate, region, rest, endpoint})
  end

  # Server
  def init(state),
    do: {:ok, state}

  # This first handler is matching on the "Leagues" endpoints,
  # that's why endpoint is nil, that arg is meant to be used with
  # the other endpoints (Matches, Runes, etc...)
  def handle_call({:handle_rate, region, rest, endpoint}, _from, state)
  when is_nil(endpoint) do
    {time, amount} = Keyword.get(@rates, region)

    {:reply, HTTP.get(region, rest, time: time, amount: amount), state}
  end

  def handle_call({:handle_rate, region, rest, endpoint}, _from, state) do
    {time, amount} = Keyword.get(@rates, endpoint)

    {:reply, HTTP.get(region, rest, time: time, amount: amount), state}
  end
end
```

Comment: How about you calculate the values for `time` and `amount` based on the value of `region`? E.g. `{time, amount} = case region do "US" -> {1, 2}; "EUW" -> {3, 4} end` and pass that to `ExRated`?

Comment: @Dogbert Oh no, I did that already, I'll edit the answer witht the GenServer I did, I'm talking about both cases of limits in development keys. What could be a good solution to support dev limits which are 20 requests each second OR 100 requests each 2 minutes.

Comment: Ah. How about something like this? `case {ExRated.check_rate("#{region}-1", 20, 1), ExRated.check_rate("#{region}-2", 100, 120)} do
  {{:ok, _}, {:ok, _}} -> ...
  _ -> ...
end`. Two counters will be incremented every time, and if any of the two hit the limit, you can abort the request.

Comment: Hmm, I think I can work with that, let me see what I come up with! @Dogbert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep two counters per region, one for the 20 requests per second limit and one for 100 requests per two minutes. Before sending the request, you can check if either of the limits have been hit and abort sending the request if so.

```
case {ExRated.check_rate("#{region}-1", 20, 1), ExRated.check_rate("#{region}-2", 100, 120)} do
  {{:ok, _}, {:ok, _}} ->
    # neither limit has been hit
  _ ->
    # one or both limits have been hit
end
```

Comment: Yes, I used this solution when you commented, thank you!